# Create suspended process and rewrite its memory space before resuming

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, 64-bit

I am analyzing code that (see below):

- Create a new process in a suspended state (`CREATE_SUSPENDED`).
- Unmap the memory space using `pZwUnmapViewOfSection()`.
- Write a new PE image (stored in the program) into the memory space.
- Set RAX to the entry point of the process.
- Resume the created process.

I want to know why this approach works.

If the code writes the PE image into new process' the memory space, then the loader does not run to resolve imports etc. - or is `CREATE_SUSPENDED` before the loader performs it job?

Furthermore, does EAX (or RAX) always holds the entry point for a PE executable when it starts?

```
/* Create suspended process for program (using current module) */
memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
if (CreateProcessA(szFileName, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi) == FALSE) {
    Debug("[Debug] RunPE(): CreateProcessA(): (%lu)\n", GetLastError());
    return FALSE;
}

/* Get thread context (processor-specific register data) */
context.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
if (GetThreadContext(pi.hThread, &context) == FALSE) {
    Debug("[Debug] RunPE(): GetThreadContext()");
}

/* Unmap memory space of program */
pZwUnmapViewOfSection = (PZUVOS)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"), "ZwUnmapViewOfSection");
pZwUnmapViewOfSection(pi.hProcess, (PVOID)pinh->OptionalHeader.ImageBase);

/* Allocate virtual memory for program */
lpAddress = VirtualAllocEx(pi.hProcess, (PVOID)pinh->OptionalHeader.ImageBase, pinh->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
if (lpAddress == NULL) {
    Debug("[Debug] RunPE(): VirtualAllocEx(): (%lu)\n", GetLastError());
    return FALSE;
}

/* Write COFF, optional and section headers into virtual memory */
if (WriteProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, (PVOID)pinh->OptionalHeader.ImageBase, fs->pBuffer, pinh->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, NULL) == FALSE) {
    Debug("[Debug] RunPE(): WriteProcessMemory(): (%lu)\n", GetLastError());
    return FALSE;
}

/* Write sections into virtual memory */
for (int i = 0; i < pinh->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++) {
    /* Compute section header of each section */
    pish = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)((DWORD)fs->pBuffer + pidh->e_lfanew + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS) + sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER) * i);
    /* Write section into virtual memory */
    WriteProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, (PVOID)(pinh->OptionalHeader.ImageBase + pish->VirtualAddress), (LPVOID)((DWORD)fs->pBuffer + pish->PointerToRawData), pish->SizeOfRawData, NULL);
}

/* Set entry-point as virtual address: address of entry point */
context.Rax = pinh->OptionalHeader.ImageBase + pinh->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
if (SetThreadContext(pi.hThread, &context) == FALSE) {
    Debug("[Debug]: RunPE(): SetThreadContext(): (%lu)\n", GetLastError());
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: pe imports, etc done by ntdll in user mode. all this begin executed only after thread will be resumed. the entry point of process will be in *rcx* register, not in *rax*.

Comment: anyway this code is incorrect, not all features, especially exception handling, etc, will be work, for code, which not inside image section

Comment: @RbMm - Thanks! Isn't the loader responsible for loading imports? If not, PE imports are loaded fine by resuming the process? Can you elaborate on what features will not work? Why won't exception handling work? Are relocations handled properly?

Comment: yes, loader load imports. this will be done, after thread resumed. relocation for exe will be not handled by loader. modern exception handling will be check that exception handler was in image section. anyway code is not correct and functional. when you view `A` api - can not look more at all

Comment: @RbMm - but the whole image is copied (headers + sections), so what is the problem? Why isn’t the code functional? Who takes care of relocation if not the loader?

Comment: exe relocated in kernel mode. all this code is wrong by design. *rax* also false

Comment: about relocation i mistake. ntdll check are `peb->ImageBaseAddress == pinth->OptionalHeader->ImageBase` and if not, call `LdrpProtectAndRelocateImage` - as result relocations also will be done (if exe have relocs). however anyway exe will be not full functional. test on notepad. run, but say open dialog - fail

Comment: May I see your example?

Comment: for example i test with [notepad](https://pastebin.com/UAKiZCtA) on win 10 x64. notepad relocated and run ok. but open dialog fail

Comment: if use another base address for exe, fail call CreateThread with `dwStackSize == 0` because in this case  system try read stack size from exe header (it address saved in `EPROCESS`). if map new image at same address as old (or not unmap old). look like exe become full functional https://pastebin.com/vRX49LTZ

Comment: @RbMm - thank you. Why does open dialog fail?

Comment: how i say, because `CreateThread` with `dwStackSize == 0` fail, if old exe base is unmapped. if we map image at same base or not unmap original image, all ok

Comment: But I don’t call CreateThread()?

Comment: process internal can call. i mean `CreateThread` fail inside child process